# How to create https-connections?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, https

I have NOT done much of web-developing and I would like to learn about it: how you can create https-connections. I am currently using apache with mysql/php as software development tools.

Are the connections/ports to be used always configured from the server or do you need some scripts for it in php? and do you need to do anything else in MySQL except enable: have_ssl ?

The tutorials that I have managed to find were a bit confusing about everything and not very thorough, So I was hoping that someone here might be so kind and explain the stuff briefly or maybe give me a link to some good tutorial.

If somebody could give me a link to some "easy to read" tutorial or briefly explain how the system works.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Apache-SSL](http://www.apache-ssl.org/) , OR [mod_ssl](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/ssl_faq.html) with-in Apache Sever

**I suggest to use mod_ssl**

if your are new to developing php/mysql try to use [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) of [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) instead of installing apache and configuring mod_ssl manually you can easily active mod_ssl in both of them if you want to do it manually

http://tud.at/programm/apache-ssl-win32-howto.php3

if you want redirect a certain path to use https instead of http ,
for example

`http ://yoursite.com/secure/ to https ://yoursite.com/secure/`

Modify htaccess file and add this

`RewriteRule "^(/secure/.*)" "https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1" [R=301,L`]

Answer (score 0):

SSL would be entirely handled by the webserver. The only thing you might do with PHP is make sure that your application is being accessed in SSL by checking if $_SERVER['HTTPS'] is set.

SSL connections to MySQL are generally not needed in a secure environment. It will add overhead to your connections that you may want to avoid.

Search for "How to configure SSL in Apache" and you will find quite a few tutorials on the subject.